# Assigning prototype chain throws TypeError in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm studying inheritance in JavaScript using prototype chaining.

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/pnyf1ska/6/

```js
// INHERITANCE USING JS

// SUPER CLASS CONSTRUCTOR
function bank () {
    this.cash = 1000;
}

// SUB CLASS CONSTRUCTOR
function thief () {
    // CALL BANK CONSTRUCTOR
    bank.call(this);
}

// ADD A METHOD TO BANK.PROTOTYPE
bank.prototype.steal = function () {
    console.log('a thief stole '+this.cash+' dollars!');
}

// THIEF EXTENDS BANK AND INHERITS STEAL METHOD.
//thief.prototype = bank.prototype;
// thief.prototype.__proto__ = bank.prototype // also works!
thief.prototype.__proto__.__proto__ = bank.prototype;  // why does this break?

let t = new thief();
t.steal();  // OUTPUT 1000.
```

Here `thief.prototype.__proto__.__proto__ = bank.prototype` breaks and outputs error:

```
"<a class='gotoLine' href='#47:37'>47:37</a> Uncaught TypeError: Immutable prototype object '#&lt;Object&gt;' cannot have their prototype set"
```

Since `thief.prototype.__proto__ = bank.prototype` works I thought `thief.prototype.__proto__.__proto__ = bank.prototype` would work as well.

Can you explain the error and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: @hev1 to demonstrate prototype chain.

Comment: Why not just `thief.prototype = bank.prototype;`? https://jsfiddle.net/f71dcbt4/

Comment: @hev1 so it goes up prototype chain of thief multiple times to find steal() method. just for demonstration.

Comment: Using it makes no sense; `thief.prototype.__proto__` just returns `Object.prototype`. And the `__proto__` of that is just null.

Comment: Please don't use jsfiddle when you can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `thief` inherit all methods and fields from `bank`, just set `thief.prototype = bank.prototype`. What you are currently using makes no sense; `thief.prototype.__proto__` just returns `Object.prototype` and the `__proto__` of that is just `null` (and is not a writable property).

```js
// INHERITANCE USING JS

// SUPER CLASS CONSTRUCTOR
function bank () {
    this.cash = 1000;
}

// SUB CLASS CONSTRUCTOR
function thief () {
    // CALL BANK CONSTRUCTOR
    bank.call(this);
}

// ADD A METHOD TO BANK.PROTOTYPE
bank.prototype.steal = function () {
    console.log('a thief stole '+this.cash+' dollars!');
}

thief.prototype = bank.prototype;

let t = new thief();
t.steal();  // OUTPUT 1000.
```